# How to get the correct app position by keyword in Google Play Search?

Tags: google-play

I open https://play.google.com/ and make a search by keyword and see my app on 5 positions.

Then I open app Google Play on Android and make search by the same keyword and see my app in 10 positions.

It turns out that each has its own issue? How then do services like appfollow.com track position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Positioning is based on a lot of factors, including your browsing history, location, language, cache and more... It is normal to have a shift in between web Play Store and app Play Store.

Web Play Store is more reactive, you will see changes more often and before the app (due to the cache system included in the app).

AppFollow uses the Google Play API, which is even wider in possibility when you give them access to your account (specially in ranking) and also some web scraping.

If you want to know more about ASO (App Store Optimization), you might be interest by those links:

https://thetool.io/aso-app-store-optimization (Initially a paid tool, but has very good articles about ASO and its factors)

*and also*

https://appsamurai.com/app-store-optimization-aso-guide/